# How to create NxM centered large buttons on one page?

Tags: html, css

I'm inexeperienced to web coding and looking for help creating my layout, with some customizable params. Basically I want #rows and #columns of buttons, large and centered, on one screen, with text above/below, as in the following:

[image]

I'm working off a very trivial example that isn't working - I need to: center things, create uniform spacing in between the buttons (and center on the page), increase button sizes, make sure the text doesn't affect the button sizes (which I can then adjust).

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<style>
.btn-group button {
  background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
  border: 1px solid green; /* Green border */
  color: white; /* White text */
  padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
  cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
  float: left; /* Float the buttons side by side */
}

/* Clear floats (clearfix hack) */
.btn-group:after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.btn-group button:not(:last-child) {
  border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group button:hover {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>
<body>

<h1 style="center">Title</h1>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button>Button 1 (sizes need)</button>
  <button>Button 2 (to be the same)</button>
  <button>Button 3 (regardless of amount of text)</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button>Button 1 (sizes need)</button>
  <button>Button 2 (to be the same)</button>
  <button>Button 3 (regardless of amount of text)</button>
</div>

<h2>Bottom Text</h2>

</body>
</html>
```

I also need it to be somewhat modular so I can scale the number of buttons: 2 or 6 or 9 or whatever (but I specify rows, columns). And no matter how many buttons are present, they should take up the same area in the "button area". If someone shows me how to do the specific example in the image above and has parameters I can probably figure it out from there.

Comment: thats exactly as task for css grid

Comment: Feel free to add an example as an answer, I'd be happy to try it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like I said, a very basic task of a CSS-Grid. YOu can style the wrapper or place it whereever you want. You can chose as many buttons as you like. you can style the btutons with a preset height, width. In the end pretty much comes down to the exact width/height values you want to have.
Espacially for such task I would use a div with an onlclick event combined with `cursor: pointer;`. It does the same job as a button but easier to style and place.

```css
.buttonGrid {
  margin: auto 20% auto 20%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.button {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttonGrid">
  <div class="button" onclick="">Button 1</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="">Button 2</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="">Button 3</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="">Button 4</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="">Button 5</div>
  <div class="button" onclick="">Button 6</div>
</div>
```